# How to overcome multiple matches within same sentence (regex)

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression to match domains like so:

`([a-z]+[0-9]{3,})+(\.net|\.com)`

I would like to exclude the domain `office365.com` from the rule, so I do:

`(?!office365\.com)([a-z]+[0-9]{3,})+(\.net|\.com)`

But the problem is that the rule above matches the `ffice365.com` of the website, so eventually I need to write:

`(?!office365\.com|ffice365\.com|fice365\.com|ice365\.com|ce365\.com|e365\.com)([a-z]+[0-9]{3,})+(\.net|\.com)`

Is there a way to overcome this behaviour?

Comment: adding word-boundaries may help. For example right between the negative lookahead and your opening of the 1st capture group. `)\b(`

Comment: How about instead of making a regex that gets bigger every time you want to exclude a website, just use code to see if "office365" exists in the string?